# Disable customHook when component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm having this error in my console:
"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

This is because my component is calling a customHook with an async call inside... but the component itself unmounts before the call returns the value I need.

```
const ResolveData = ({ dispatch }) => {
  const [loading, error] = setPermission(dispatch);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("canceled");
    };
  }, []);

  return ...;
};
```

my hook "setPermission" dispatch a value and that value made the component reload again (useReducer is in the father).
When the component reloads, It calls the customHook again, but the component is unmounted...
Ot at least, that's what I've understood of the problem.

This component Redirects me to another Component, using the variable returned by the customHook.

This is my customHook

```
export default dispatch => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserPermission = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await requests.getData("/url"); //my URL
        dispatch({
          type: "dispatch_type",
          payload: response.data.role
        });
      } catch (err) {
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        setError(true);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    if (getToken()) {
      getUserPermission();
    }
    return () => {
      const cancelToken = createCancelToken();
      cancelToken.cancel("canceled");
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return [loading, error];
};
```

Any help on how to disable the customHook call when component is Unmounted?

Comment: Can you also share the code in your custom hook? I think the logic applied is not ideal. Your call to the API should be called inside an useEffect. Also, you don't have to send dispatch as a parameter. You can use the hook useDispatch inside your custom hook.

Comment: @SantiagoBendavid I'm not using Redux, I'm using the useReducer from "react". My customHook, uses a useEffect to make the call.

Comment: I still believe it'd be best if you share the code in your custom hook, otherwise it's a hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: @SantiagoBendavid done

Comment: Try removing `dispatch` from the useEffect inputs array in your custom hook. That way getUserPermission should only be called once.

Comment: @SantiagoBendavid Ok thanks, It's calling It one time, but I still need to manage how to call It without that parameter... sometimes It's needed. I need to make it more "variable" but It's ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my implementation of `useApi` looks like:

```js
// libs
import axios from 'axios';
import { useReducer, useRef } from 'react';

export const actionTypes = {
  SET_LOADING: 'SET_LOADING',
  SET_DATA: 'SET_DATA',
  SET_ERROR: 'SET_ERROR',
};

export const fetchData = async (dispatch, cancelToken, action, params) => {
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SET_LOADING });

  return action(params, cancelToken)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(payload => {
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SET_DATA, payload });
      return payload;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (!axios.isCancel(error)) {
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.SET_ERROR, error });
        throw error;
      }
    });
};

const initialState = { isLoading: false, payload: {}, error: null };

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload, error } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_LOADING:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: null };
    case actionTypes.SET_DATA:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: null, payload };
    case actionTypes.SET_ERROR:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, error };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

/**
 * Reusable hook to make api calls using a function (action).
 * It handles cancellation of previous requests automatically.
 *
 * @typedef State
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} payload - Api response.
 * @property {boolean} isLoading - status of Api call.
 * @property {object} error - error object in case of failed call.
 *
 * @typedef ExecuteAction
 * @type {function}
 * @param {object} params - params to pass to action
 * @returns {Promise} - resolves with payload
 *
 * @typedef useApi
 * @param {function} action
 * @returns [State, ExecuteAction, cleanupAction]
 */
const useApi = action => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const axiosSource = useRef(null);
  const cleanupAction = () => {
    if (axiosSource.current) {
      axiosSource.current.cancel('Cleaned up previous request.');
    }
  };
  const executeAction = (params = {}) => {
    cleanupAction();
    axiosSource.current = axios.CancelToken.source();
    return fetchData(dispatch, axiosSource.current.token, action, params);
  };

  if (!action || typeof action !== 'function') {
    throw Error('Missing action || type of action is not function.');
  }

  return [state, executeAction, cleanupAction];
};

export default useApi;
```

You can use it in your component like:

```js
const getData = (params, cancelToken) => axios.post('some url', params, { cancelToken });

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [state, fetchData, cleanup] = useApi(getData);
  const { isLoading, error, payload } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
   fetchData({ key: 'some params to pass to getData action' });
   return cleanup;
  })
}
```

You can tweak `useApi` as you like.

Comment: Thanks, that's not exactly what I needed to solve the problem, but anyway, I can start from this to build a better structure.